# Linux: Weak link an entire library, like OS X ld -weak-lfoo

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

On OS X, `ld` has a handy option `-weak-l`, which is like `-l`, but the library is linked 'weakly'.  If the lib can't be found when the executable is loaded, no errors are raised until the program actually encounters a symbol it can't find.

```
g++ -L. -weak-lfoo -o main.out main.cpp
```

Is there an equivalent feature in the Linux `ld` command?  I can't find it.

I'm trying to avoid this error:

```
./main.out: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...even if `libfoo.so` is not available.  (I happen to know that -- for my use case -- `main.out` won't be calling any functions that require symbols from `libfoo.so`.)

Answer (score 1):

afaik, there is no such thing.

At least some recent (2017-03-22) discussion in the [Debian-devel mailinglist](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/03/msg00272.html) suggests that this would be a nice-to-have feature (thus implying that it doesn't exist)